# The significance of a basis of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

I find myself quite confused about bases of vector spaces, and exactly what they represent.

For if you consider the $3D$ real space, it is $3-$tuple of real numbers. In a geometrical context, what is it that they represent? If $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ belongs to the $3D$ real space, then it can be represented in different ways as different linear combinations of different basis vectors.

So exactly what does the 'raw' $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}^3$ represent geometrically? I find myself confused with how it all comes together, and would be much obliged if someone could clearly explain this.

Comment: But to my understanding, ℝ3 is the x-y-z plane which is again represented by basis vectors (1,0,0),(0,1,0) and (0,0,1). If you do a basis transformation, it spans the same space but the points are represented differently. So I think what I want to know is, does a vector space exist because of its basis Vectors? Does the R3 triple have any meaning independent of the basis vectors in a geometrical context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, an ordered $n$-tuple of elements $(v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)$ of $V$ is said to be a *basis* of $V$ if

1. The set $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ is *linearly independent*. That is, the equation $\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_i = 0$ implies that each $c_i=0$. One way to remember this definition is that the only linear combination of the $v_i$ equal to the zero vector is the trivial one.
2. $V=\operatorname{Span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$. That is, for any $w\in V$, there exist $c_1, \ldots, c_n\in F$ such that $w=\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_i$.

Condition 1 implies that an element $w\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements in at most one way. Condition 2 implies that each element in $w\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements in at least one way. Together, these yield the important fact:

> For each $w\in V$, there exists a *unique* set of scalars $\{c_1, \ldots, c_n\}$ such that $w=\sum_{i=1}^n c_iv_i$.

For example, let $V=\mathbb R^3$ and $F=\mathbb R$. The standard basis is $((1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1))$. Any element $(x_1, x_2, x_3)\in\mathbb R^3$ can be written uniquely as $x_1(1,0,0) + x_2(0,1,0) + x_3(0,0,1)$.